# Jekyll using pipe operator in where_exp

Tags: filtering, jekyll, liquid

I am using Jekyll 3.8. My posts contain `date` attribute set. Some of them contain values from the past (e.g. `2001-01-01`), some of them from the future (e.g. `2109-12-31`).

What I would like to achieve is to display only posts that are in the past (so that their date is smaller than `now`). Now, I've managed to get it done using:

```
{% capture current_time %}{{'now' | date: '%s'}}{% endcapture %}

{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% capture post_time %}{{post.date | date: '%s'}}{% endcapture %}
  {% if post_time >= current_time %}
           DISPLAY THE ITEM
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but it's not efficient.

I would like to have it done using where_exp filter. Now - is it possible?
My draft looks like:

```
{% capture current_time %}{{'now' | date: '%s'}}{% endcapture %}
{% assign filtered_posts = site.posts| where_exp:"post","post.date | date: '%s' >= current_time" %}

{% for post in filtered_posts %}
   DISPLAY THE ITEM
{% endfor %}
```

but I'm receiving `Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 5): comparison of Time with String failed in source.md`.

I suppose, that the problem lies in `| date: '%s'` from `{% assign filtered_posts = site.posts| where_exp:"post","post.date | date: '%s' >= current_time" %}`.

Therefore:

1. **can I even use filters (pipe) in the `where_exp` expressions?**
2. If not, then - can I somehow cast the post.date to string without filters, or cast current_time to string and make the comparision work at the same time?

Comment: A helpful discussion regarding thie issue can be found here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error as `where_exp` is throwing an error because of the pipe in the comparison expression.

Nevertheless, you can compare post.date which is a Time object to site.time (generation time) to get posts that are in the past.

```
{% assign filtered_posts = site.posts | where_exp: "post","post.date <= site.time" %}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time. This works! In fact, your solution bypasses the problem, as now it is comparing the dates.

Anyways, the problem is that my particular scenario is slightly more convoluted than "toy" problem I've described in the question, because I am comparing __now + 5 days__ (`date: '%s' | plus: 432000`) and post's date - and I need filters  for that...

Comment: @mcnesium eventually I ended up with a bunch of `capture`s and two `for` loops. Liquid is a bit limited, and to be honest even "where_exp" already feels like a hack

Comment: @JackL. sorry I deleted my comment before I saw your answer. But I came up with a solution that worked for me pretty well, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, which I described in detail [in the Jekyll community forum](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/site-time-tomorrow/6658/). It is about getting a list of future events including today, and the OP's similar approach did not work here as well:

```
{% assign events_list = site.events | where_exp: "event", "event.date >= site.time | date: %F" %}
```

So I created a [filter plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/your-first-plugin/#filters) in `_plugins/to_time.rb`, which converts a string to a Time object:

```
module Jekyll
    module AssetFilter
        def to_time(date_string)
            DateTime.parse(date_string).to_time
        end
    end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::AssetFilter)
```

This first parses the string to a DateTime object and then uses [this to_time function](https://apidock.com/rails/Date/to_time) to make a Time object.

Then I assign a variable with the current time, apply the pipe operator with the filter I need, and then I add the `to_time` filter in the end:

```
{% assign today = 'now' | date: '%F' | to_time %}
```

Using `now`, then using `%F` to just get the date part of it, then converting it back to Time, so `today` will be todays date at 0:00 in the morning.

Then I can compare it with the `date` object from my events collection items:

```
{% assign events_list = site.events | where_exp: "event", "event.date >= today" %}
```